# What does '?' mean in the context of a Query in Springboot

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT Students 
FROM department 
WHERE department.id=?1
```

What exactly is **?1** in this query?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Look up parameter place holders.

Answer (score 1):

The Question Mark ( ? ) there is used as a placeholder.
Used with 1 it means that is should look something like this:

variable + "1" resulting a concatenation of  "variable1"

ex: if placeholder variable is "5" you will have:
"Select Students from department where department.id=51"